# iPhone 14 Nook Orientation Problem

Tags: nook

Recently my nook app on my iPhone 14 switched to landscape mode.  Normally, you just change the orientation of the phone to change the viewing mode.  But it seems stuck there.  It is very annoying.  Any ideas how to reset it the viewing mode so it naturally changes when I change the orientation of the phone.  Note, all other apps that support the change in orientation feature work as expected, it is just the Nook app that is stuck.